# Tor not starting

Tags: configuration, error

Tor had been working fine for a while, but I modified the torrc file and tried to restart and now it will not start again. I removed the edit but now it still will not start. Terminal Output:

```
[root@EU1 ~]# /etc/init.d/tor status
tor is not running
[root@EU1 ~]# /etc/init.d/tor start
Raising maximum number of filedescriptors (ulimit -n) to 16384.
Starting tor:                                              [  OK  ]
[root@EU1 ~]# /etc/init.d/tor status
tor is not running
[root@EU1 ~]#
```

Other Terminal Output:

```
[root@EU1 ~]# tor --service start
Feb 07 08:52:50.002 [notice] Tor v0.2.5.10 (git-42b42605f8d8eac2) running on Linux with Libevent 1.4.13-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips and Zlib 1.2.3.
Feb 07 08:52:50.002 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Feb 07 08:52:50.002 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Feb 07 08:52:50.004 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option 'service'.  Failing.
Feb 07 08:52:50.004 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
[root@EU1 ~]#
```

Contents of my torrc file:

```
HiddenServiceDir /home/tor/www/.config/1
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:3036
```

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Is Tor allowed to write to `/home/tor/www/.config/1`?

Comment: how does someone get help with this problem when they don't know what the *&%& you are talking about? By the way in case you are wondering that's probably most of us.

Comment: # Permissions on directory /var/lib/tor/hidden_service are too permissive. $chmod 700 /home/tor/www/.config/1

Answer (score 4):

You're starting it wrong. You perhaps want `service tor start`, depending on your OS.

What you're doing here is running Tor, as root, with commandline arguments of `--service start`. Tor has never heard of the `--service` option, so it says so and closes.

(That said, my guess is that your underlying problem is that your Tor daemon doesn't have permission to write to `/home/tor/`. Your Tor logs should say something like this, but Tor might be exiting before it gets around to writing out that log line.)

Comment: I have started it many times with the command `/etc/init.d/tor start` and the `tor --service start` I found in the Tor documentation. The output of `tor --service` is `[warn] Command-line option '--service' with no value. Failing.` which leads me to believe it is a command.

Comment: Output of `service tor start` is this: `[root@EU1 ~]# service tor start
Raising maximum number of filedescriptors (ulimit -n) to 16384.
Starting tor:                                              [  OK  ]
[root@EU1 ~]# service tor status
tor is not running
[root@EU1 ~]#
` same error

Comment: Last time I ran into this error I *think* I fixed it by editing the torrc file, but I cant seem to find anything wrong with it now, given its only two lines

Comment: The `--service` option is for Windows, where it starts, stop or removes a Windows service.